# Updating recyclerview using findViewHolderForLayoutPosition

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-recyclerview

We are creating a chat application using `openfire`, `smack`. In that there is a chatscreen where users can send and receive messages and media files. For storing messages we are using Realm as local db. I want to show the progress of files during upload of files.

My Upload file code is :

```
public void firebasestorageMeth(final String msg, final String path, final String filetype, final String mykey, final String otheruserkey, final String username) {
    StorageReference riversRef = STORAGE_REFERENCE.child(mykey).child("files").child(GetTimeStamp.timeStampDate());
    final String timestampdate = GetTimeStamp.timeStampDate();
    final String timestamptime = GetTimeStamp.timeStampTime();
    final long id = GetTimeStamp.Id();
    ChatMessageRealm cmr = new ChatMessageRealm(mykey + otheruserkey, otheruserkey, msg, mykey, timestamptime, timestampdate, filetype, String.valueOf(id), "0", "",path);

    ChatHelper.addChatMesgRealmMedia1(cmr, this, mykey, otheruserkey);
    sendBroadcast(new Intent().putExtra("reloadchatmediastatus", MEDIA_STARTING).putExtra("reloadchatmediaid", String.valueOf(id)).putExtra("reloadchatmedialocalurl", path).setAction("reloadchataction"));

    Log.d(TAG, cmr.getChatref()+cmr.getMsgid()+cmr.getMsgstring()+"file path extension upload file" + path);

    riversRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)))
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                umpref.setUri(String.valueOf(id), path);
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Log.d(TAG, "file uploaded" + downloadUrl);
                ChatMessageRealm cmr = new ChatMessageRealm(mykey + otheruserkey, otheruserkey, msg, mykey, timestamptime, timestampdate, filetype, String.valueOf(id), "1", String.valueOf(downloadUrl),path);
                ChatHelper.addChatMesgRealmMedia1(cmr, getApplicationContext(), mykey, otheruserkey);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent().putExtra("reloadchatmediastatus", MEDIA_SUCCESS).putExtra("reloadchatmediaid", String.valueOf(id)).putExtra("reloadchatmediaurl", String.valueOf(downloadUrl)).putExtra("reloadchatmedialocalurl", path).setAction("reloadchataction"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                sendBroadcast(new Intent().putExtra("reloadchatmediastatus", MEDIA_FAILED).putExtra("reloadchatmediaid", String.valueOf(id)).putExtra("reloadchatmedialocalurl", path).setAction("reloadchataction"));
                exception.printStackTrace();

            }
        })
        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                int progress = (int) ((100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                sendBroadcast(new Intent().putExtra("reloadchatmediastatus", progress + " ").putExtra("reloadchatmediaid", String.valueOf(id)).putExtra("reloadchatmedialocalurl", path).setAction("reloadchataction"));

            }
        });
}
```

The chatadapter code is :

```
public class ChatAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter1.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<ChatMessageRealm> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private UserSession session;
    public static final int SENDER = 0;
    public static final int RECIPIENT = 1;
    String TAG = "ChatAdapter1";

    public ChatAdapter1(ArrayList<ChatMessageRealm> list, Context context) {
        this.mList = list;
        this.context = context;
        session = new UserSession(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mList.get(position).getSenderjid().matches(session.getUserKey())) {
            return SENDER;
        } else {
            return RECIPIENT;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case SENDER:
                View viewSender = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_chats_sender, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(viewSender);
                break;
            case RECIPIENT:
                View viewRecipient = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_chats_receiver, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(viewRecipient);
                break;
        }

        return (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ChatAdapter1.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ChatMessageRealm comment = mList.get(position);

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

//        holder.otherSender_sender.setText(comment.getSenderjid());
        holder.otherSender_Timestamp.setText(comment.getSendertime() + "," + comment.getSenderdate());
//        holder.status.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        switch (comment.getMsgtype()) {
            case "text":
//                holder.btndown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String decryptedmsg = comment.getMsgstring();
                holder.commentString.setText(decryptedmsg);
//                holder.photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case "photo":
                Glide.clear(holder.imgchat);
                holder.imgchat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (getItemViewType(position) == SENDER) {
//                    holder.btndown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    holder.btnopen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    try {
                        Glide.with(context).load(comment.getMsglocalurl()).into(holder.imgchat);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView otherSender_Timestamp, commentString,progress;
        public ImageView imgchat;
        public Button btndown, btnopen;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            otherSender_Timestamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.meSender_TimeStamp);
            commentString = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentString);
            progress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaprogress);
            imgchat = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgchat);
            btndown = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndown);
            btnopen = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnopen);

        }
    }

}
```

ChatActivity code is:

```
public class ChatActivity extends ToadoBaseActivity {

    private EditText typeComment;
    private ImageButton sendButton, attachment, takephoto;
    Intent intent;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference dbChat;
    private String otheruserkey;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private MarshmallowPermissions marshmallowPermissions;
    private ArrayList<String> mResults = new ArrayList<>();
    private ActionMode actionMode;
    UploadFileService uploadFileService;
    boolean mServiceBound = false;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm aa");
    private ChatAdapter1 mAdapter;
    LinkedHashSet<ChatMessageRealm> uniqueStrings = new LinkedHashSet<ChatMessageRealm>();
    private ArrayList<ChatMessageRealm> chatList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> chatListIds = new ArrayList<>();
    String username, mykey;
    private UserSession session;
    String receiverToken = "nil";
    boolean clicked;
    LinearLayout layoutToAdd;
    LinearLayout commentView;
    private ChildEventListener dbChatlistener;
    ImageButton photoattach, videoattach;
    Uri videoUri;
    public String dbTableKey;
    EncryptUtils encryptUtils = new EncryptUtils();
    private ImageButton imgdocattach;
    private ImageButton locattach;
    private LinearLayout spamView;
    TextView tvTitle;
    ImageView imgprof;
    private ArrayList<String> imagesPathList;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 199;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    UserMediaPrefs umprefs;
    private Boolean mBounded;
    private String TAG = "ChatActivity";
    //    AbstractXMPPConnection connection;
    Realm mRealm;
    Boolean chatexists;
    private String otherusername;
    private String profpic;
    private MyXMPP2 myxinstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat1);
        session = new UserSession(this);
        mykey = session.getUserKey();

//        connection = MyXMPP2.getInstance(this,).getConn();
        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        checkChatRef(otheruserkey);

        clicked = false;
        layoutToAdd = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.attachmentpopup);
        marshmallowPermissions = new MarshmallowPermissions(this);

        spamView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.spamView);

        umprefs = new UserMediaPrefs(this);

        //get these 2 things from notifications also
        intent = getIntent();

        otheruserkey = intent.getStringExtra("otheruserkey");
        otherusername = intent.getStringExtra("otherusername");
        profpic = intent.getStringExtra("profpic");

        System.out.println("recevier token chat act oncreate" + otheruserkey);

        imgprof = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_profile);
        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(otherusername);
        commentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.commentView);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

        typeComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeComment);
        sendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        attachment = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.attachment);

        takephoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.takephoto);
        photoattach = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoattach);
        imgdocattach = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.docattach);
        videoattach = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.videoattach);
        locattach = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.locationattach);
        myxinstance = MyXMPP2.getInstance(ChatActivity.this, getString(R.string.server), mykey);

        mAdapter = new ChatAdapter1(chatList, this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(mykey + " chat created " + otheruserkey);
                ChatMessageRealm cm = null;
                if (!typeComment.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    cm = new ChatMessageRealm(mykey + otheruserkey, otheruserkey, typeComment.getText().toString(), mykey, GetTimeStamp.timeStampTime(), GetTimeStamp.timeStampDate(), "text", String.valueOf(GetTimeStamp.Id()), "1");
                }
                if (cm != null)
                    myxinstance.sendMessage(cm);

                loadData();
                typeComment.setText("");
            }
        });

        attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (layoutToAdd.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    layoutToAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    layoutToAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        takephoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    anfe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mykey = session.getUserKey();
        username = session.getUsername();
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        Sort sort[] = {Sort.ASCENDING};
        String[] fieldNames = {"msgid"};
        RealmResults<ChatMessageRealm> shows = mRealm.where(ChatMessageRealm.class).equalTo("chatref", mykey + otheruserkey).findAllSorted(fieldNames, sort);
        if (shows.size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, shows.size() + "LOAD DATA CALLED " + shows.get(shows.size() - 1).getMsgstring());
            for (ChatMessageRealm cm : shows) {
                if (!chatList.contains(cm)) {
                    chatList.add(cm);
                }

                if (!chatListIds.contains(cm.getMsgid())) {
                    chatListIds.add(cm.getMsgid());
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatList.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    private void checkChatRef(String otheruserkey) {
        RealmQuery<ActiveChats> query = mRealm.where(ActiveChats.class);
        query.equalTo("otherkey", otheruserkey);
        RealmResults<ActiveChats> result1 = query.findAll();
        if (result1.size() == 0) {
            chatexists = false;
        } else {
            chatexists = true;
        }
        System.out.println(result1.size() + "chat exists chatactivity" + chatexists);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(this.reloadData, new IntentFilter("reloadchataction"));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (reloadData != null)
            unregisterReceiver(reloadData);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() throws IOException {
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
                .start(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "request code chatactivity" + requestCode);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {

                if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "crop activity");
                    CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        final String imguri = result.getUri().toString();
                        try {
                            final File file = createImageFile();
                            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                @Override
                                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                    final int chunkSize = 1024;  // We'll read in one kB at a time
                                    byte[] imageData = new byte[chunkSize];

                                    InputStream in = null;
                                    OutputStream out = null;
                                    try {
                                        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(imguri));
                                        out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                                        int bytesRead;
                                        while ((bytesRead = in.read(imageData)) > 0) {
                                            out.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(imageData, 0, Math.max(0, bytesRead)));
                                        }
                                        String s = file.getAbsolutePath();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "image cropped uri chatact22" + file.getAbsolutePath());
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, ImageComment.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("URI", s);
                                        intent.putExtra("comment_type", "photo");
                                        startImageComment(intent);

                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        Log.e("Something went wrong.", ex.toString());
                                    } finally {
                                        try {
                                            in.close();
                                            out.close();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }.execute();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name

        String imageFileName = "pic-" + GetTimeStamp.timeStamp() + ".jpg";
        File image = OpenFile.createFile(this, imageFileName);
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        Log.d(TAG, "file createimagefile: " + image.getAbsolutePath());
        return image;
    }

    private void startImageComment(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "image comment sending" + intent.getStringExtra("URI"));
        intent.putExtra("username", username);
        intent.putExtra("otheruserkey", otheruserkey);
        intent.putExtra("receiverToken", receiverToken);
        intent.putExtra("mykey", mykey);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver reloadData = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra("reloadchat") != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, " reloading data broadcast receiver" + intent.getStringExtra("reloadchat"));
                loadData();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediastatus") != null) {
                if (intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediastatus").matches(MEDIA_STARTING))
                    loadData();

                Log.d(TAG, " reloading data status " + intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediastatus"));
                Log.d(TAG, " reloading data media id " + intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediaid"));

                if (!intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediastatus").matches(MEDIA_FAILED)) {
                    final String msgid = intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediaid");
                    String fileprogress = intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediastatus");
                    int ind1 = chatListIds.indexOf(msgid);
                    Log.d(TAG, ind1 + "chat list broadcast progress " + fileprogress);
                    Log.d(TAG, "chat list broadcast" + chatListIds.size());
                    try {
//                        View ve = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(ind1);
//                            View v = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(ind1).itemView;
                        View v = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(ind1).itemView;
                        ChatAdapter1.MyViewHolder holder = (ChatAdapter1.MyViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                        holder.commentString.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.commentString.setText("file prog " + fileprogress);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Log.d(TAG, holder.getItemViewType() + "," + holder.getLayoutPosition() + "," + holder.commentString.getText().toString() + " VIEW HOLDER? " + v);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediaurl") != null)
                Log.d(TAG, " reloading data media url " + intent.getStringExtra("reloadchatmediaurl"));

        }
    };

}
```

I am trying to update my recyclerview dynamically in the broadcast receiver- `reloadData` in ChatActivity.
My logs tell me that i am receiving correct data from the sendbroadcast in the UploadFileService, the problem is in following code inside the broadcast receiver on ChatActivity, it is getting correct data but the data is not showing on the recycler  view:

```
try {
    View v = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(ind1).itemView;
    ChatAdapter1.MyViewHolder holder = (ChatAdapter1.MyViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
    holder.commentString.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.commentString.setText("file prog " + fileprogress);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, holder.getItemViewType() + "," + holder.getLayoutPosition() + "," + holder.commentString.getText().toString() + " VIEW HOLDER? " + v);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get correct values , such as:

```
08-03 19:31:25.240 705-705/com.app.toado D/ChatActivity: 0,30,file prog 34  VIEW HOLDER? android.widget.LinearLayout{ff24ae0 V.E...... ......I. 0,621-660,1380 #7f1100f2 app:id/message_container}
08-03 19:31:26.346 705-705/com.app.toado D/ChatActivity: 0,30,file prog 100  VIEW HOLDER? android.widget.LinearLayout{e8a33ce V.E...... ......I. 0,621-660,1380 #7f1100f2 app:id/message_container}
08-03 19:31:26.347 705-705/com.app.toado D/ChatActivity: 0,30,file prog upload success VIEW HOLDER? android.widget.LinearLayout{e8a33ce V.E...... ......I. 0,621-660,1380 #7f1100f2 app:id/message_container}
```

I have tried using `View ve = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(ind1);` and `View v = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(ind1).itemView;` but they are also not working. Also tried adding notifydatasetchanged to it.

The try catch is also not throwing any error in the logs.

Can someone please help in figuring out why are the changes not showing on the recycler view but are showing in logs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're updating the `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` from the UI Thread? Whenever you try to update the `ViewHolder`, you have to be certain you're doing so on the UI or it will not behave as expected.

When the modification to the `ViewHolder` is changed, check that `Looper.myLooper().equals(Looper.getMainLooper());`. If it returns `false`, it means you aren't updating on the UI Thread, the necessary place for all graphical updates to be made.

If this is the case, you just need to make sure that you can synchronize your changes on the UI, using `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable r);`.

Comment: i logged `Looper.myLooper().equals(Looper.getMainLooper());` and it is returning true

Comment: i was able to solve the problem, i created a method in adapter like this `public void setProgress(MyViewHolder holder , String progress){
        Log.d(TAG, holder.getItemViewType() + " LOOPER check " + (holder.progressbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE));
        holder.otherSender_Timestamp.setText("file prog " + progress);
        holder.commentString.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.commentString.setText(progress);
        holder.progressbar.setIndeterminate(true);
        holder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }`. i took hint from your suggestion thanks!

Comment: if u could add the above to your answer it might be helpful to others.